# Codeigniter Loop Updates records with single data

Tags: php, loops, codeigniter, for-loop

I am trying to edit student's scores. like the image below. Each time I add the scores to be edited, my loop updates all the scores with only the last score in the form found below the picture of the form, my code and the SQL result when data has been edited.

[image]

Below is the code on my controller.

```
$fetch_session = $this->Home_model->SemesterSession();
$session = $fetch_session[0]->session;
$semester = $fetch_session[0]->semester;

// Form data
$unit = array();
$score = array();
$course = array();
$matno = $this->input->post('matno22');
$dept = $this->input->post('department22');
$level = $this->input->post('level22');
$score1 = $this->input->post('score');
$course1 = $this->input->post('c_code');
$unit1 = $this->input->post('unit');

// for each

    for ($i=0;$i<count($course1);$i++) {
        $data['score'] = $score1[$i]; //1
        $data['unit'] =  $unit1[$i];
        $data['matno'] = $matno;
        $data['level'] = $level;
        $data['dept'] = $dept;
        $data['course'] = $course1[$i];
        $data['semester'] = $semester;
        $data['session'] = $session;

        if ($data['score'] >=69) {
            $data['grade'] = 'A';  //2
$data['remark'] = 'Excellent'; //5
$data['grade_point'] = '5';  //3
$data['quality_p'] = $data['unit'] * $data['grade_point']; //4
        } elseif ($data['score'] >= 59) {
            $data['grade'] = 'B';
            $data['remark'] = 'Very Good';
            $data['grade_point'] = '4';
            $data['quality_p'] = $data['unit'] * $data['grade_point'];
        } elseif ($data['score'] >=49) {
            $data['grade'] = 'C';
            $data['remark'] = 'Good';
            $data['grade_point'] = '3';
            $data['quality_p'] = $data['unit'] * $data['grade_point'];
        } elseif ($data['score'] >=44) {
            $data['grade'] = 'D';
            $data['remark'] = 'Fair';
            $data['grade_point'] = '2';
            $data['quality_p'] = $data['unit'] * $data['grade_point'];
        } elseif ($data['score'] >=39) {
            $data['grade'] = 'E';
            $data['remark'] = 'Poor';
            $data['grade_point'] = '1';
            $data['quality_p'] = $data['unit'] * $data['grade_point'];
        } else {
            $data['grade'] = 'F';
            $data['remark'] = 'Fail';
            $data['grade_point'] = '0';
            $data['quality_p'] = $data['unit'] * $data['grade_point'];
        }

        // Edit The Scores
        $query = $this->Home_model->EditResult($data);

        if ($query == true) {
            $response['Error'] = 'false';
            $response['Message'] = 'Result Successfully Modified';
        } else {
            $response['Error'] = 'true';
            $response['Message'] = 'Error Modifying Result';
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

here is my model

```
public function EditResult($data) {
    $condition = "matno = " . "'" . $data['matno'] . "' AND " . "course =" . "'" . $data['course'] . "' AND " . "semester =" . "'" . $data['semester'] . "' AND " . "session =" . "'" . $data['session'] . "'";      
        $this->db->where($condition);
    $this->db->update('result', $data);
    }
```

Lastly,  This is what happens on my DB table when I update the scores

[image]

Comment: Have you done some basic debugging, like `print_r($_POST)` to double check *exactly* what your form is sending?  Also, it looks like your code is open to SQL injection, by using submitted user values raw in your `$condition`.  Don't do that!  [Look into query bindings or at least escaping](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html).  Also - it looks like your SQL is quoting most fields (`"`), even though they are numbers? You'll get better performance if you don't do that (assuming the coltypes are numeric in your schema).

Comment: Thanks. I got it resolved. Thanks for the pointing out my error in my $condition. I have fixed that.